# Visual Studio 2022 suddenly makes file name uppercase

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

During normal work session Visual Studio 2022 suddenly makes `*.cpp` existing file name uppercase.
I can't realize when it happens and why. Just one random file name and extension becomes upper case.

Some existing file **MyFile.cpp** becomes **MYFILE.CPP** on disk.

The file name in VS Solution Explorer is still CameCase. The changes affect only file name and extension on disk and following search results and new bookmarks.

Am I the only person who meets this? What could be the cause?

**Update**

As *Žilvinas Vaira* mentioned in the answer below, most likely it comes from *Call Hierarchy* tab with the only reservation that I have the same defect with not read-only files. Just can't reproduce the sequence of steps. If somebody would, please share.

Comment: Did you notice in Solution Explorer that all the files you created were capitalized?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT, no in Solution Explorer the file is still CamelCase. Updated the question.

Comment: Are you using any extension or git  hooks that may be trying to change the case? Perhaps due to a bug they uppercase the name instead of lowercasing it? If you use git you'll be able to check the history to see what changed when

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, no extensions, no git. Pure latest version of Visual Studio. No idea when this happens, since I don't track for this intentionally and notice only when see in search results or path to bookmarks.

Comment: @DamirTenishev If you try to use Visual Studio Installer to repair or update Visual Studio, will this solve this issue?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT, I met this issue already 3-4 times and amid all these times I upgraded VS using Visual Studio installer (now I have the recent version). Does it count?

Answer (score 2):

It happens for me from time to time. I have noticed that it might be coming from the call hierarchy tab. Is seems that if I open a file from call hierarchy list and that file is marked as read only (and is not open yet), it will change it's name to all capitals...

Comment: I don't have read-only files, but just caught the same with Call Hierarchy tab. Can't reproduce the sequence of actions, but will keep an eye on this. If you find a way to reproduce, please let me know.